# Remove parent categories from subcategory in URLs in 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento-1.9, category, url-rewrite

Magento version is 1.9.2.3.

I have tried following solution which doesn't work for me.

Step 1: Go to `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php` copy this file to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php` because it is core Magento file so that we have to copy that file into the `app/code/local`.

Step 2: Now search for the `getCategoryRequestPath($category, $parentPath)` around line 698 in Magento ver. 1.9.1.0

Step 3: Search `if (null === $parentPath)` around line 717 and comment the line as below:

```
/* if (null === $parentPath) {
$parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
}
elseif ($parentPath == '/'){*/
$parentPath = ''; //DO NOT Comment this line
//}
```

Step 4: Now Go to the Magento admin and Clear Cache System->Cache Management and Reindex System->Index Management the data.

Step 5: Refresh your browser cache and navigate again now you will see only the Sub Category in Url not the Parent Category just like as: `http://www.abcxyz.com/test-category-level-1-3.html`
[See more.](http://www.expertwebadvisor.com/remove-parent-category-path-from-sub-category-url-in-magento/#sthash.cy3HvxwW.dpuf)

I have also tried this solution which doesn't work for me.

Suppose you want to remove parent category path from url such as
Url-> **www.domain.com/cat1/cat2** to **www.domain.com/cat2**

USAGE :

1. Go to the Magento Admin Panel -> System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Seo Options
2. Select yes or no from "Use Parent Category Path for Category URLs"
3. Refresh category url index.

Option YES => www.domain.com/cat1/cat2

Option NO => www.domain.com/cat2

Help me if you have another solution

Answer (score 0):

When You Override the file `Url.php`. You just need to edit line number 726 that has below code:

```
$requestPath = $parentPath . $urlKey . $categoryUrlSuffix;
```

change it to below code :

```
$requestPath = $urlKey . $categoryUrlSuffix;
```

Then update it. No need to edit `$parentPath`.

Flush Magento cache and it should work.

It worked for me.